# Handle backstack of android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Currently, I have a Fragment stack like this.

**F1 -> F2 -> F3 -> F4 -> F5**

And in an activity, I have five buttons **B1, B2, B3, B4, and B5.**

My question is when I press **B1** button from the activity how can I update Fragment stack like below.

**F2 -> F3 -> F4 -> F5 -> F1.**

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the questions, but I'm assuming you mean you wish to pop off F5, F4, F3, and F2 so you are back to F1.  Assuming they are all added to the some container view (and not sub-fragments), you can use `FragmentManager.popBackStack("F1", 0)`.  This also assumes that you have used `String` tags for your fragments when they were added.  If instead you used `int` IDs, then use the version of that API which takes the `int` ID of the `Fragment` you wish to end on.

Comment: I used string tags when added to the back stack. I used **FragmentManager.popBackStack("F1", 0)** this but it was not doing that I want to. And thanks for responding. Now you can see my question B1, B2, B3, B4, and B5 are buttons in activity.
.

Comment: The button details don't really help to explain what you are wanting.  Are you trying to remove F1 from the "bottom" of the fragment back stack and move it to the "front"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Can you know how to do this?

Comment: That's a bit more challenging.  You may be able to try removing the F1 fragment, committing then replacing F5 with F1 as a transaction pushed to the back stack.  You may be better off managing the fragments yourself along with hooking the "back" trigger.